# django - ValueError: <model> needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, django-models

Say, I have a model `Post` which has many to many relation to built-in `User` for `liked_post`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    like = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked_posts')
```

All is going nice for the logic, I can add/remove the like relation nicely.
But when I introduce additional attribute `save` for `saved_post`, like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    like = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked_posts')
    save = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='saved_posts')
```

It always throw an error below when I'm trying to even instantiate the `Post` model.

```
ValueError: "<Post: Post object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Note that I did not even modify/add any custom `save()` method.

The error just pops up even when I'm trying to call `p = Post.object.create()`.

From what I have known, I need to save `Post` first before adding any `like` or `save` relation. But I got error even from saving a Post instance.

====

**Edit 1**

Include a full stack trace:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rahmat/Upworks/06_Made_Gatewee/gatewee/app_post/tests/test_post_save.py", line 34, in setUp
    p = Post.objects.create()
  File "/home/rahmat/Upworks/06_Made_Gatewee/gatewee/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahmat/Upworks/06_Made_Gatewee/gatewee/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/rahmat/Upworks/06_Made_Gatewee/gatewee/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 527, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "/home/rahmat/Upworks/06_Made_Gatewee/gatewee/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 840, in __init__
    (instance, self.pk_field_names[self.source_field_name]))
ValueError: "<Post: Post object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Comment: Did you successfully ran `make migrations` and `migrate`? Also include the **full** traceback message.

Comment: @PedramParsian yes, I did `makemigrations` and `migrate` with no problem.

Comment: I think _(almost sure)_ the error is because your `save` field **conflicts** with some internal workflow; try renaming it to something like `saved_posts` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @PedramParsian Greatly appreciate your help! I wouldn't have guessed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `save` field in `Post` model **conflicts** with the internal `save` method and cause this error.

Simply changed the field name, like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    like = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked_posts')
    saved_posts = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='saved_posts')
```